# Moving dynamic method call to class library causes a RuntimeBinderException in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic, actor, dataflow, tpl-dataflow

I was reading an [interesting article using of DataFlow + dynamic method invocation to make an Actor model in C#](http://www.jayway.com/2013/11/15/an-actor-model-implementation-in-c-using-tpl-dataflow/).  Here is the completed example verbatim.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public abstract class Message { }

    public abstract class Actor
    {
        private readonly ActionBlock<Message> _action;

        public Actor()
        {
            _action = new ActionBlock<Message>(message =>
            {
                dynamic self = this;
                dynamic mess = message;
                self.Handle(mess);
            });
        }

        public void Send(Message message)
        {
            _action.Post(message);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public class Deposit : Message
        {
            public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        }

        public class QueryBalance : Message
        {
            public Actor Receiver { get; set; }
        }

        public class Balance : Message
        {
            public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        }

        public class AccountActor : Actor
        {
            private decimal _balance;

            public void Handle(Deposit message)
            {
                _balance += message.Amount;
            }

            public void Handle(QueryBalance message)
            {
                message.Receiver.Send(new Balance { Amount = _balance });
            }
        }

        public class OutputActor : Actor
        {
            public void Handle(Balance message)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Balance is {0}", message.Amount);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var account = new AccountActor();
            var output = new OutputActor();

            account.Send(new Deposit { Amount = 50 });
            account.Send(new QueryBalance { Receiver = output });

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This works as intended.  Moving Actor & Message classes into a new class library and referencing properly causing an issue.  When run it throws a RuntimeBinderException on the dynamic `self.Handle(mess);` within the Actor constructor saying `Actors.Actor does not contain a definition for 'Handle'`.  Are there limitations to dynamic method calls I can't seem to find in the MSDN or syntax magic I missing to do this from a separate class library?

Answer (score 1):

The original author got back to me.

> Hi,
>
> The problem is that you have declared your messages and actors inside
>   the internal NotWorkingProgram class.

```
class NotWorkingProgram  // no access modifier! Default is 'internal' {
    public class Deposit : Message
    ...
    public class AccountActor : Actor
    {
        public void Handle(Deposit message)
        ...
    } }
```

> When you run the program the runtime tries to find a method named
>   'Handle' with a parameter of typ 'Deposit'. It can't find anything
>   because the AccountActor class is not visible from the Actors Project.
>   It is hidden inside the invisible NotWorkingProgram. If you make the
>   NotWorkingProgram class public (or move the Deposit and AccountActor
>   classes outside) it works!
>
> Regards Johan

I'm leaving this here cause the RuntimeBinderException doesn't give much info, let alone any hint of class/method privacy being a possible root